# Broken library in Django 1.6 - urls reverse / NoReverseMatch even when templates corrected

Tags: django, django-1.6

Using django-pendulum and trying to get it to work w/the latest Django 1.6. Using a sample blank project, it seems to break trying to reverse urls. I even escaped the {url..} syntax in the templates but no luck. Any ideas on how this can be fixed to work w/1.6? It worked in 1.5!

EDIT - here is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /pendulum/
Reverse for 'pendulum-clock-in' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/pendulum/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'pendulum-clock-in' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

and

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_pendulum-0.1.6_pre4-py2.7.egg\pendulum\templates\pendulum\pendulum_base.html, error at line 8
Reverse for 'pendulum-clock-in' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
1   {% extends 'base.html' %}
2   
3   {% block content %}
4   {% block pendulum-controls %}
5   <div id="pendulum-controls">
6       <ul class="pendulum-controls">
7   {#        <li><strong>{{ emp }}</strong></li>#}
8           <li><a href="{% url 'pendulum-clock-in' %}">Clock In</a></li>
```

Comment: Seems django-pendulum has old style `url` tag and its not compatible with django 1.6. It should look like `{% url 'view-name' arg %}`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: The url tag syntax changed in Django 1.5 so if it works in 1.5 it should work in 1.6. Please include the full traceback and the template that is causing problems.

Comment: I had already fixed the urls but it still won't resolve. There are no arguments for this url. BTW - the source for django-pendulum is here: https://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-pendulum

Comment: Have you included pendulum's urls from your main urls.py?  `(r'^pendulum/', include('pendulum.urls')),`